# Count how many UL Elements there are in a Div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, count, html-lists, removechild

I am dynamically adding UL elements to a DIV element. I would like to be able to count how many UL elements there are inside the DIV so that once all the ULs are removed dynamically I can delete the DIV that they are contained in.

```
<div id="000">

<ul id="000-1">
<li>Stuff</li>
<li>Stuff</li>
</ul>

<ul id="000-2">
<li>Stuff</li>
<li>Stuff</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Is there a simple Javascript solution that counts the amount of ULs so that I can do something like this.. ?

```
if(ulcount == 0){

var remove = document.getElementById("000");
remove.innerHTML = '';
results.parentNode.removeChild("000");

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Cheeso's answer is a good pure-JS solution. But, if you're using jQuery, the process can be made simpler.

```
jQuery('div#000').children('ul').length;
```

The above code will return the number of child `ul` elements of the `div#000`.

To update the count when you add elements dynamically, you will have to create a function and  call it to update the number whenever a change occurs:

```
function countUls() {jQuery('div#000').children('ul').length;}
```

Bind that to an event so that it will be called when you want to update the number.

Comment: Can I use this jQuery solution in conjunction with exsisting javascript functions?

Comment: @Wezly Certaily! jQuery is a JavaScript library, so it can be used alongside standard JavaScript.

Comment: A simpler solution could be `$("#000 > ul").length` - an ID is unique and there is a child selector as well.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
    function getDirectChildrenByTagName(elt,tagname) {
        var allChildren = elt.children, wantedChildren=[], i, L;
        tagname = tagname.toUpperCase();
        for(i=0, L=allChildren.length; i<L; i++) {
            if (allChildren[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == tagname) {
                wantedChildren.push(allChildren[i]);
            }
        }
        return wantedChildren;
    }
```

use it like this:

```
var zero = document.getElementById("000");  
var uls = getDirectChildrenByTagName(zero, 'UL');
var ulCount = uls.length;
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("000-1").querySelectorAll("li").length
                  console.log(">>>>", x);
```